# What security mechanisms enable a user to change their password under a Kerberos environment?

Tags: kerberos

During client authentication, neither the secret key nor the password is sent to the KDC.  If a user changes their password on the client, how is the password updated in the password database in the KDC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specifications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cat-kerb-chg-password-02), when the user changes passwords, the password is sent, encrypted by authenticator subkey (from the prior authentication), to the server.  The server then checks that it is valid and updates the user's information with the new password.